# How to put post title or keyphrase in content on different places automatically?

Tags: title, content, automation

I want to repeat my title/keyword in different places in my content.

for example, my title is "Dog"

I want to replace "Dog" everywhere I have inserted *** or any hint.

how this is possible easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search-replace those placeholders with `the_content` filter.

```
function custom_the_content( $content ) {
    return str_replace('{placeholder}', get_the_title(), $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_the_content');
```

Note: I don't recommend using `***` or similar as a placeholder, as it can be commonly used. That is why I've used `{placeholder}`.

**UPDATE:** Based on the comments below, if you need to search-replace multiple values within `the_content` filter, use arrays as `str_replace` arguments like below:

```
function custom_the_content( $content ) {

    // Search for these elements
    $search = array(
        '{apktitle}',
        '{apkversion}',
    );

    // And replace them with these (the order of array items is preserved)
    $replace = array(
        get_the_title(),
        get_datos_info('version'),
    );

    return str_replace( $search, $replace, $content );
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_the_content');
```

Comment: Do i need to put this code in Functions.php and (placeholder) should be text which i want to replace with title? 

Thanks bro, please confirm how to use this code. Just adding in functions.php will work?

Comment: @MuhammadImran Yes, adding this code to functions.php will work. Yes, `{placeholder}` is the text that will be replaced with the post title.

Comment: @Filo, can you can please give any hint to create any field like Title.  I want to replace multiple values with multiple placeholders.

Comment: i have created a custom field using plugin, field name is app_version, how can call it as we can call title ?

Comment: If the custom plugin you are referring to is Advanced Custom Fields, then you would call it like this: `get_field('app_version')`. However this is very well documented in official ACF documentation and it is out of scope of this stack, you should check it out.

Comment: @Filo please help me in calling and replacing multiple things. If I use this function twice I get an error: Cannot redeclare custom_the_content() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/appyn/functions.php:1795)

Comment: 'function custom_the_content( $content ) {
    return str_replace('{apktitle}', get_the_title(), $content);
    return str_replace('{apkversion}', get_datos_info('version'), $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_the_content');'

Comment: @MuhammadImran you can't re-declare the same function twice. Also you can't put multiple `return` statements after each other, because once the value is returned from the function, other returns are never reached. Check my updated answer and use arrays as `str_replace` arguments, the order of array items is preserved, so the first item of `$search` array will be replaced with the first item of `$replace` array, etc.